# XNA and SLI

Tags: xna, sli

I'm looking at buying a new gaming PC on which to do some XNA development.  Before I buy a machine with SLI graphic cards, does anyone know if XNA has any problems taking advantage of a SLI setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only consideration you need to make with XNA is the shader profile you code to ... that is, if you write custom shaders at all :-)  aside from that, as long as the video card is dx9+ compatible, you should usually be fine.

*Edit:* According to the list of *[Supported Operating Systems and Hardware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203925.aspx)* for XNA Game Studio 3.1

> To run XNA Framework games on a
>   computer running a Windows operating
>   system, you need a graphics card that
>   supports, at a minimum, Shader Model
>   1.1, and DirectX 9.0c. We recommend using a graphics card that supports
>   Shader Model 2.0 because some samples
>   and starter kits may require it.

Furthermore, according to [NVidia's marketing material](http://www.nvidia.com/object/powerof3.html), the following cards are SLI, and support up to shader model 3.0

- NVIDIA GeForce 7900 GPUs
- NVIDIA GeForce 7800 GTX
- NVIDIA GeForce 7800 GT
- NVIDIA GeForce 7600 GPUs
- NVIDIA GeForce 6800 Ultra
- NVIDIA GeForce 6800 GT
- NVIDIA GeForce 6800 GS
- NVIDIA GeForce 6800
- NVIDIA GeForce 6800 XT
- NVIDIA GeForce 6600 GT
- NVIDIA GeForce 6600
- NVIDIA GeForce 6600 LE

Comment: I am/will be writing custom HLSL shaders but am kinda new to that scene so am not sure how I would go about writing something in HLSL which would be specific to SLI.

Hopefully that means I won't - but it would be useful to know how you would do it, so I can avoid it :)  Any resources gratefully accepted.

Comment: updated the post with more specific information :-) good luck!

Comment: You don't need to tailor HLSL for specific cards, in an SLI setup the card should act just as if it's one really awesome card - so no worries there :)

Answer (score 3):

XNA is abstracted away from the hardware.  I don't believe you can write code specific to certain cards (if you can you shouldn't).  If you had that kind of code, you wouldn't be able to move the project over to an xbox 360.  I believe you would want to go the directx route if you plan on using card specific features.

That being said, if you you a working SLI setup, you would surpass any [minimum requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203918.aspx).

Comment: Also keep in mind it is very easy to write a game that works great on your computer but will eat the Xbox fir dinner. (Especially if you work with SLI or Crossfire)